# Rails, collection_check_boxes, maximum picked

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form which uses collection_check_boxes for an input.

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :color_ids, group.colors, :id, :name
```

I would like to prevent users from checking more than n boxes in the form.

I know how to do it in the model, I just need the views part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to use jquery.

1 In the view I put the maximum amount at the end of the class like this:

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :color_ids, group.colors, :id, :name, item_wrapper_class: "bla bla2 #{group.maximum.to_s}"
```

2 When an input[type=checkbox] is clicked I find how many others are marked

```
$(this).parent().parent().siblings().children().children(':checked').length
```

3 I find the maximum allowed value from step 1 by the following line

```
max = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().attr('class').split(' ').pop());
```

4 I compare the maximum allowed with the checked and prevent from checking if the first one is less. The whole code looks like this

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(evt) {
    var max;
    max = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().attr('class').split(' ').pop());
    if ($(this).parent().parent().siblings().children().children(':checked').length + 1 > max) {
      this.checked = false;
    }
  });
```